# SMS Send through Journey Builder - Help with the Contact Model

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

For using the contact data in Journey Builder while sending SMS do we need to use the MobileConnect attribute group? Can I have my own data extensions and a separate attribute group bypassing the Mobile Connect attribute group? If yes then how do I connect the contact?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: are you using this in a decision split? if so as long as its linked in data designer you can use it.

Comment: Thanks, how do I connect that data extension with the contact record, I'll not have email data in my data extension?